# how to zimbra api import contacts in php it's possible?

Tags: zimbra, cakephp-2.8

I have to import contact details of zimbra mail account to my web application. how to proceed with zimbra application.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this repository :
https://github.com/jorgedlcruz/zcs-php

This at present doesn't seem to be having a contact api call but should be helpful to get started and implement the call as per your requirement to the Zimbra Soap Api's.